# How to call NtUserPostMessage from kernel-mode WFP callout driver?

Tags: c++, windows, windows-8, driver, wfp

In order to fit a WFP (Windows Filtering Platform) callout driver into an existing product, I need to have it send window messages to an existing application. Is there a way to do this from a kernel-mode WFP driver?

There's a technique [here](http://x1machine.blogspot.com/2010_08_01_archive.html) for calling NtUserPostMessage from kernel-mode drivers, but I'm not sure if it applies to a WFP driver and it predates Windows 8 so it doesn't have the right syscall address for the new OS.

I'm open to any method of sending window messages (or, more precisely, posting them so there won't be a delay) because it would keep me from having to recode part of the existing app.

Comment: Could you have a user-mode application running to post the messages on behalf of your driver?

Comment: And how would they communicate? With DeviceIoControl?

Comment: That would be the simplest and probably the best approach.  I think you could use a named pipe instead if you preferred, or you could use shared memory and an event object.

Answer (score 0):

I think best method would be to have IOCTL interface between user and kernel mode.
You can use this method https://www.osr.com/nt-insider/2013-issue1/inverted-call-model-kmdf/. 
This allows you to send data also between user & kernel mode.